# Specific ContentPage Title Font size on android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So i have created a navigation bar, in which I want to make the title-font smaller for users on Android.

I figured that I could do something like this:

```
<ContentPage.Title>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Size">
        <On Platform="Android">8</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Title>
```

But it doesn't work, and I get a compiler error.

Therefore, how do I correct my code, or preferably write some reusable code in App.xaml in order to declare a platform-specific font-size, for my navigation titles.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22825/how-to-change-title-font-for-navigation-bar

Comment: There are several errors with the suggested code

Comment: Which did you use?

Comment: Did you make the [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the custom renderer to set the font size.
For example:
In the pcl project create a `MyNavigationPage.cs`:

```
public class MyNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public MyNavigationPage(Page root) : base(root)
    {

    }
}
```

And create the renderer class in android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]    
namespace NavigationBarFontSize.Droid
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;

        public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
        {
            base.OnViewAdded(child);
            if (child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar))
            {
                toolbar = child as Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
                toolbar.ChildViewAdded += Toolbar_ChildViewAdded;
                var a = toolbar.ChildCount;
            }
        }

        void Toolbar_ChildViewAdded(object sender, ChildViewAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            var view = e.Child.GetType();
            if (e.Child.GetType() == typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView))
            {
                var textView = e.Child as Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView;
                textView.TextSize = 50;
                toolbar.ChildViewAdded -= Toolbar_ChildViewAdded;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you could use it by:

```
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
            MainPage = new MyNavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
```